# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Xcode 6 to run a single current test function under cursor?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, swift

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Xcode 6 to run the current test case under cursor? I know I can press <kbd>Command</kbd> +  <kbd>u</kbd> to run all tests. Also, I can tap the test icon located to the left of the test function or tap the icon in 'Test Navigator'. Is there a **keyboard shortcut** to run only the single test function under cursor?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Run the current test:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Re-Run the last test:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: Has this changed in Xcode 8.2.1? I type control-option-command-U and all the tests in the current file are run.

Comment: "Run the current test" as in the test or test class the cursor has focus in.

Comment: @Daniel make sure the cursor is currently within the test case before using the shortcut

Comment: To add to this, if you want to run ALL tests in the current file, you can hit command-A to highlight the entire file, then control-option-command-U.

Answer (score 5):

`control-option-command G` will let you rerun your last test.  So if you run a single test the first time and then keep running it (a common workflow for TDD), that might save you some time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode key binding preferences for these commands are:

- Perform Action - Test
- Perform Action - Test Again

Use those titles to find the commands for re-binding.

Comment: Does anybody have any clues why after Xcode 10.2 update 'Product - Perform Action - Test' menu item stays inactive until the selected line is not the test class name?